# Issue with intent filter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

this is my `intent filter`

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"  android:mimeType="*/*"  />
            </intent-filter>
```

I want that on click of XML file my app is launch and checkboxes are checked( ID stay into XML file).
When i click on XML file saved into storage of my device, my app is launch; but checkboxes are not checked, i don't know why...this is my code:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            String intenttt=intent.getData().toString();


            //System.out.println("INTENT:"+intenttt);
            //File filee = new File(intenttt);
            File file = new File(intenttt);
            System.out.println("FILE:"+file);

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            . . .
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.